# Retrieve all contacts that sent emails to a Gmail address

Tags: gmail, export

I have one Gmail account to receive emails from users. Right now I want to create a list for all users **whom ever sent** an email to this Gmail account. Basically, I want a list with all the **From:** email addresses. So that I can have one list to send updates or notifications to them with the email list.

How can I do that?

Comment: So you want a list with all the "from" contacts, right?

Comment: yes, that is exactly right. I need create "cc" email list of all the email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[eeemail.net](http://eeemail.net) allows you to get ( extract, export ) all email addresses from your correspondence not only from the address book but from every email you ever sent or received. Seems to support popular web mail services like Google (GMail), Yahoo, Hotmail, Aolmail etc.

---

Please note their condition for extracting the contacts:

> **All contacts will receive notification about this service**

Comment: but eeemail.net it's free. so it's fair