# How to export a list of all emails addresses that I have sent mail to in Gmail

Tags: gmail, export

I am trying to get a list of all emails that I have sent an email to using my Gmail account. I am using Google Apps if that makes any difference.

**Update:** I have found [this website](http://www.labnol.org/internet/extract-gmail-addresses/28037/), but it only looks at the sender of the emails, whereas I am looking for a list of recipients.

Comment: That's why I said "similar".  If you read the answers though, it's trivial to get the `to:` addresses as well.

Answer (score 0):

If configured to do so, Gmail should memorize all the addresses you ever sent an email to (*Settings* → **Create contacts for auto-complete**), so you should find all these addresses under **Other Contacts**, in *Contacts*. From there, you can just export them or do whatever you want to do with them.

[image]

Otherwise, see the solution suggested in [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/19878/1512).